# Solving for distance and time. Please help, I am stuck, and need to know how to do this please.

Tags: trigonometry

A ship is 4 degrees off course.  If the ship is traveling at 10 miles per hour, how far off course will it be after 6 hours

Comment: Uhhh... still $4$ degrees?

Answer (score 2):

A good thing to ask on many trigonometry problems is: where can I find a triangle?  Our triangle must have two legs and a hypotenuse.  Let $P$ be the point at which the ship heads $4$ degrees off course.  If the ship had continued on the right course we would get a line from $P$ to some point $Q$ that is $10\cdot 6=60$ miles long.  Since the ship did go off course, the actual path will be a line from $P$ to some point $R$ that is $60$ miles long and forms an angle of $4$ degrees with the line $\overline{PQ}$.  Now connected $R$ and $Q$ with a line.  The length of $\overline{QR}$ will be how far the ship is off course.

Comment: If, instead of turning, the ship had stopped, would you say it was 60 miles off course after 10 hours?

Comment: @User58220  I'm guessing you hope I say "no".  But, I don't think that's so obvious.  It is $60$ miles from where it should be.

Comment: Yes, and it would be $0$ miles from the track it wanted to be on.  So now all we need is the meaning of "off course", the second way that the original post uses it...:)  Using the "from where it should be" definition, your answer is correct...

Answer (score 0):

We have an equilateral triangle PQR where $PQ=PR=60$ and $QR=x,\angle PQ=4^{\circ}$ perpendicular from $P$ split that triangle in two right triangles from on of them we get that $\sin 2^{\circ}=\frac{QR/2}{60}$ (see answer from Joe)
$$QR=120\sin 2^{\circ}$$

Comment: can you explain why you used sin of 2 degrees instead 4 degrees. thank you very much this really helped me.

Comment: Could "off course" be interpreted as "distance right or left of intended track"?